# Eclipse Juno SVN issues

Tags: eclipse, svn

I'm using Eclipse Juno v4.2.0 on Mac OS X 10.6, all Polarion Subversive SVN Connectors and Subversive SVN Team provider v1.0.0|20120601-1700.

The SVN repository is only reachable through a VPN.
I have checked out the ressources with the "Find Projects in the children of the selected resource" option. 
Every time I start Eclipse, I HAVE TO have a connection to the VPN. Otherwise SVN says, that the repository location had changed and I have to relocate my working copy OR it would be disconnected. 
This is really annoying, beause in Helios and Indigo this never happened and I don't need to be connected to the VPN. Is there an option which I missed to prevent Eclipse to check the location on startup?

Comment: i would probably report this as a regression bug at http://bugs.eclipse.com...